# Modularising Database Returns AngularJS

Tags: html, mysql, json, ajax, angularjs

My application makes an ajax call to a database, receives the data in JSON form then creates a table based on the results of the query.
My issue is that I have multiple pages doing this with different calls to the database, returning different numbers of columns and rows. Also, when a user clicks on a row, all the information pertaining to that row should be displayed (there are lots of chained one to many relationships, where a list of type 1 is shown, each of which has a list of type 2, each of which has a list of type 3 etc.)
Currently I can see no way to sensibly modularise the javascript so that one controller displays database results. The HTML isn't too hard to do:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2> {{ header }} <h2>
    <div class="well" style="overflow: auto">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="column in cols"> {{ column }} </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-click="more(row)" ng-class="setClass(row)">
                    <td ng-repeat="column in cols"> {{ row[column] }} </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will display a table with the data. I was hoping to get the function `more(row)` to use some information about the row to display the next query, possibly the first column, but the JSON data is done by named indexes for example the first column might be `table1id` and `table2id` for a different database.
Currently I can't see any way of handling this except for creating a new controller for every possible table I'm creating for example:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'identityFactory', 'databaseFactory', function ($scope, identityFactory, databaseFactory) {
    $scope.query = JSON.stringify({
        'username': identityFactory.getLoginPair()[0],
        'password': identityFactory.getLoginPair()[1],
        'query': 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1;'
    });
    databaseFactory.querydb($scope.query).then(function (response) {
        $scope.rows = angular.fromJson(response.data);
        $scope.cols = Object.getOwnPropertyNames($scope.rows[0]);
    }, function (response) {
        $scope.rows = response.data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = response.status;
    });
    $scope.setBsClass = function (row) {
        if (row['ColName'] == 'Condition') {
            return 'danger';
        };
    };
}]);
```

Can anyone see some way of effectively modularising this, because I have a lot of pages that are all doing something very similar where the select statement is the main thing that differs, and also the conditional bootstrap formatting.

Comment: directives can help modularize a lot by passing in config from controllers.